# Why won't my Ember template render?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, javascript-framework

[Here's a fiddle for this question](http://jsfiddle.net/Gqc53/5/) (add/remove single slash on line 5 and re-run)

Basically, two ways of binding (*proper term?*) my application template. I would expect both ways to work, but one works, and one doesn't.

### Works

```
this.register( 'view:application',     Ember.View.extend());
this.register( 'template:application', Ember.Handlebars.compile( 'Hello, world!' ));
```

### Broken

```
this.register( 'view:application', Ember.View.extend({
  'template': Ember.Handlebars.compile( 'Hello, world!' )
}));
```

This seems to be the case for all resources/routes, not just at the application level.

*So, why doesn't the second method work?*

**Edit**: Here's a [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSaF3/1/) that shows a Handlebars view helper successfully using method 2 (broken) above. It seems it's only an issue for route views.

**Edit 2**: Thanks to [c4p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844923/c4p) Here's an Issue on Github

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676017/ember-js-rc1-view-not-displayed-when-specifying-template).

Short summary:

- Ember expects to find templates in the global variable `Ember.TEMPLATES`. When you use Ember.Handlebars.compile, the compiled templates are put into the global variable `Handlebars.templates`.
- If you want to use the compiling this way, you have to do something like this:

---

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['posts-template'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('I am the template');
App.PostsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'posts-template'
});
```

Comment: This issue is also discussed here:  github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2030

Comment: If you use a handlebars view helper, you can use plain `template` *or* `templateName` -- http://jsfiddle.net/TSaF3/1/